# MapKit Map - annotation Not show on Simulator

Tags: ios, swift, annotations, apple-maps

I am trying to show markers in the mapview while loading it but the map is showing my countrymap in the mapview but not the annotations. is there anything wrong i am doing? FYI my simulator location is set as Apple.

```
import MapKit
import UIKit

class Capital: NSObject, MKAnnotation {
    var title: String?
    var coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D
    var info: String

    init(title: String, coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D, info: String) {
        self.title = title
        self.coordinate = coordinate
        self.info = info
    }
}





import MapKit
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController, MKMapViewDelegate {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let london = Capital(title: "London", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 51.507222, longitude: -0.1275), info: "Home to the 2012 Summer Olympics.")
        let oslo = Capital(title: "Oslo", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 59.95, longitude: 10.75), info: "Founded over a thousand years ago.")
        let paris = Capital(title: "Paris", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 48.8567, longitude: 2.3508), info: "Often called the City of Light.")
        let rome = Capital(title: "Rome", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 41.9, longitude: 12.5), info: "Has a whole country inside it.")
        let washington = Capital(title: "Washington DC", coordinate: CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 38.895111, longitude: -77.036667), info: "Named after George himself.")

         mapView.addAnnotations([london, oslo, paris, rome, washington])
    }
}
```

Comment: I have added the images which has the code that I tried.

Comment: We cant debug your error until we dont have code snippet. And no one will write code from your images.

Comment: Please have a look at it now, kindly ignore if I haven't posted my query well, this is my first time posting a question here.

Answer (score 1):

**Try This**

```
import UIKit
import MapKit



 class MapViewController: UIViewController {
        @IBOutlet var mapView: MKMapView!

        let location:CLLocationCoordinate2D = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 20.5937, longitude: 78.9629)


        override func viewDidLoad() {
            super.viewDidLoad()



            let anotation = MKPointAnnotation()
            anotation.coordinate = location
            anotation.title = "The Location"
            anotation.subtitle = "This is the location !!!"
            mapView.addAnnotation(anotation)

        }
}
```

Comment: Your code works like charm. I have a situation like i will ping a web service that gives me annotation details for various locations and then I have to create these annotations and show them in the map so I have used an approach with a separate class that conform to the mkannotation (as you can see in my query )and then i am trying to add all of them at once and that is not working as I expected. I can't utilize your approach as I won't be adding only one point annotation in the map. Please let me know if you have any ideas, thanks a ton.

Comment: [Read This](https://www.raywenderlich.com/90971/introduction-mapkit-swift-tutorial) It will helpful to you

Comment: I am also not able to annotate a point that is out my country, I have tried adding only one point that is out of my country still the simulator only shows my country map and no annotations.Any solution for it?

Comment: Impossible > It will show all annotation if it exist on earth. You need to zoom In your map using **You can use Option (Alt) button or combination of Option button and command button along with mouse movement to zoom in and zoom out a map or an image.** and check again.

Comment: I am a bit embarrassed to say this, my code in the query I have mentioned is working all right, when I run it in the simulator it is just showing my country map but i did not see annotations i have added. Just now  I have realised that i am  so dumb to zoom in the map in simulator to the locations where i have added pins and they exist there safe and sound. anyways thanks for your help man @IDeveloper. I couldn't have zoom in the map in my simulator until you say so.:)